# Resampling of a pandas dataframe with non-equidistant timestamp column as time line

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame object representing sensor measurements. The dataframe has a column **Timestamp** and several columns for the data of the sensors. The timestamps are not equidistant. The problem iam facing is, that i want the dataframe to be resampled to (if possible) equidistant timestamps by filling the gap between two consecutive measurements with the previous sensor values.

See the example below as an example:

The original dataframe with the timestamps based on a change of a sensor value:

```
pandas.core.DataFrame(columns=["Timestamp","SensorA","SensorB"],
                      data=[
                            [ pd.Timestamp("2022-10-01 10:30:01.500" , 1.5, 3.5) ],
                            [ pd.Timestamp("2022-10-01 10:30:01.800" , 2.0, 3.5) ],
                            [ pd.Timestamp("2022-10-01 10:30:01.900" , 2.0, 4.0) ] 
                           ])
```

What i want to get is, Timestamps with a difference of x-milliseconds if possible -> If an existing sample conflicts, the existing sample is to be used. For concrete example, the resample time should be *200ms*. See the expected output below: The new sample at the timestamp **...700** was added to get a timestamp between **...500** and **...800** to get the distance to near *200ms*. For the samples at **...800** and **...900** no rows were added since the measurements are nearer than the selected *200ms* timespan (Excisting values are not to be changed):

```
pandas.core.DataFrame(columns=["Timestamp","SensorA","SensorB"],
                      data=[
                            [ pd.Timestamp("2022-10-01 10:30:01.500" , 1.5, 3.5) ],
                            [ pd.Timestamp("2022-10-01 10:30:01.700" , 1.5, 3.5) ],
                            [ pd.Timestamp("2022-10-01 10:30:01.800" , 2.0, 3.5) ],
                            [ pd.Timestamp("2022-10-01 10:30:01.900" , 2.0, 4.0) ] 
                           ])
```

My current solution is not very performant since it iterates over the dataframe rows and adds the resampled rows in a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
# ensure datetime
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])

out = (df.set_index('Timestamp')    # temporarily set Timestamp as index
         .resample('1min').ffill()  # resample and ffill
         .reset_index()[df.columns] # restore index/columns
      )
```

*NB. assuming "Index" is the DataFrame's index.*

Output:

```
             Timestamp  SensorA  SensorB  ...
0  2022-10-03 10:30:00        1        2  ...
1  2022-10-03 10:31:00        1        2  ...
2  2022-10-03 10:32:00        1        2  ...
3  2022-10-03 10:33:00        2        3  ...
4  2022-10-03 10:34:00        3        3  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also stumbled over the builtin .resample function of pandas but it does not fit to my requirements since it changes the existing rows to fit the timespan that is requested. In your example, the problem what i mean is that a sample with a timestamp of **2022-10-03 10:30:32** becomes **2022-10-03 10:31:00** for your selected 1min resampling interval.

Comment: Can you update your example (please in an easily reproducible format, the one with the lines is a pain to copy)

Comment: I edited the question to use dataframes. Please have a look.